# How to optimize the algorithm to find the max_depth_contact_series in a time varying graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

Assuming there is a time varying graph with `N` nodes named `a1,a2,...,an` and contact series as `t node1 node2` meaning `node1` contacts with `node2` at time `t`

Assuming node `a1` carries a message(there is only one copy of the message in the graph), from time `0`, how many nodes can the message  contact with at most in time `T`? The message can be transferred to another node freely at anytime. For example, `a1` can chose to transfer it to `a2` at time `2` or keeps the message until `a1` contacts with `a3` and transfers it to `a3`.

Here is an example to make it more clear. For a graph with `6` nodes and contact series:

`1 a1 a2`
`2 a1 a3`
`3 a1 a4`
`4 a3 a5`
`6 a3 a6`
`10 a4 a3`

During time `0~10` the message can contact with `4` nodes at most:`a2,a3,a5,a6` with message tranferred from `a1` to `a3` at time `2`.

Keep in mind the time series. Here `a1` carries the message but transfers the message to `a3` at time `2`. Then at time `3` node `a1` has no message so the message cant contact with `a4`. If `a1` keeps message at time `2` instead of tranferring to `a3`, the message contacts with  the list `a2,a3,a4,a3`. The contact set will be `{a2,a3,a4}` with size `3` which is smaller than `4`.

How can I get the largest contact nodes set? Or just the number?

At present I get it with recursive algorithm but the cost is unbearable when `T` is large.

Comment: Not clear why `a4` is not in the result list. Looks like a simple diffusion algorithm, so to maintain a set of contacted node from time to time seems to be very simple. Could you please clarify ?

Comment: I have re-edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: No that's not clear. Why at 3 a1 doesn't have the message? At 1, it already gave it to a2 so why is it available at 2??? Seems to be inconsistent

Comment: The node with message can decide when to transfer the message. `a1` can tranfer the message at time `1` or `2` or `3` or any time when there is a contact with another node. The purpose is to maximize the number of node which contacts with the message.

Comment: Ok then as I understand the problem is the longest path problem. That problem is known as NP-hard, which means that there is probably no efficient algorithm to solve it. It may exists some more efficient algorithms is your graph has some peculiar properties.